# Multiple primary keys in rails? -- (rails beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, primary-key

I have a table that holds data received from a thirdparty via an api and has the default **id** field that rails adds upon running the migration. I also have a primary key which I receive the from the third party which I need to store and use in my business logic. Without doing the following, the relations from other models don't work:

```
class ThirdPartyStuff < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_primary_key :thirdpartysID

  ...

end
```

Is that ok to do? Any pit falls or problems that might arise?

Comment: do you mean that you have diferents primary keys in the same table?

Comment: One added by rails automatically (id) and the one I get from third party data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have a primary key per table (the pk can contain more that one field but still only one PK).

If you want a column to act like a PK: set it as `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`. If you want to reference another table: create a `Foreign Key`.

Comment: But the migration still generates the **id** field if I drop the entire db and run the migration -- is that nornal?

Comment: Or do I have to set this field as the primary_key somehow in the migration as well?

Comment: yes, remember PKs are used to indentify a row when operating in the table, so use that id column as your PK and add the other columns you need.